# Solution for mapping corporative credentials with Ethereum account

Tags: dapps

I need a solution for mapping corporative credentials (like Active Directory) to users of a "corporative Ethereum account".
In other words, all users of the company may use the same Ethereum account. So, I would like to have a signer application that anyone with a corporative credential can use. I need to log who is using the signer to submit the transactions to the blockchain. What are some solutions to that?
Thank you

Comment: This stack is not made so that we design your solution. Just use classic software design and you'll get it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it goes:

`User => shared account, singleton => contract`

Now, it should *probably* be set up so the users don't actually hold the corporate signing credentials. Think about employee turnover and restricting the extent of what authorized employees can actually do. It will probably be best to validate what they are doing and keep in a narrow band of what they *should* be doing.

I would incline to an off-chain solution with a server. Given the server the credentials (secure it) and have the employess interact with an app, api, something else.

`User => server => contract`

If you do that, then the server can authenticate the users (Active Directory). Since the server would know who is sending instructions, it could also inform the contract. If the functions will accept something that identifies the user, possibly obfuscated like a hash of the their AD username then the contract could emit events with an identifier thatindicates WHO caused something to happen. Take extra care to thoroughly obfuscate usernames so nothing useful is leaked publicly. Whatever it is, it is merely a comment for the log.

The functions would be `onlyOwner` or `onlyServer` so it would clear that only the server can do these things and it is, therefore, the server that is claiming a certain person is responsible for the action.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I definitely agree with your proposal of using an off-chain server application. Thank you. It seems a module that would be useful in many scenarios. I am wondering if there is a ready solution for that.

Comment: I think I would approach it as a simple server app that presents the contract functions through an API and looks after the user-identification function. Full stop. That should be enough for out-of-scope building of other modules to "do stuff." It would be a nice demarkation point between teams.